# In Perl, how to dereference temp hash passed as argument?

Tags: perl

In Perl, how to dereference temporary hash passed as argument to function?

```
MyFunct({ 
    Param1 => "knob1",
    Param2 => "knob2"
});

# this part never seems to work...
sub MyFunct {
    my %param = %{shift()};
    my $p1 = $param{Param1};
    print "p1: $p1\n";
}
```

Comment: The code you showed works fine. Please show a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that we can use to reproduce the problem you're having.

Answer (score 3):

Your code works as is.

```
$ perl -e'
    MyFunct({
        Param1 => "knob1",
        Param2 => "knob2"
    });

    # this part never seems to work...
    sub MyFunct {
        my %param = %{shift()};
        my $p1 = $param{Param1};
        print "p1: $p1\n";
    }
'
p1: knob1
```

That said, you are needlessly making a copy of the referenced hash. The following is a better approach:

```
$ perl -e'
    MyFunct({
        Param1 => "knob1",
        Param2 => "knob2"
    });

    sub MyFunct {
        my $param = shift;
        my $p1 = $param->{Param1};
        print "p1: $p1\n";
    }
'
p1: knob1
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176527/discussion-on-answer-by-ikegami-in-perl-how-to-dereference-temp-hash-passed-as).

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @ikegami's answer, I'll add that perhaps you do not need a reference.  Passing in the values as key/value pairs will make it easy to convert the list into a hash, using the implicit argument array `@_`.

The key/value pairs can be performed by using the arrow `=>` delimiter, or in its place a standard comma `,` delimiter.  Below is an example using the arrow.

#### [IDEOne Example](https://ideone.com/NcowXI)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

MyFunct( 
  Param1 => "knob1",
  Param2 => "knob2"
);

# this part never seems to work...
sub MyFunct {
  my %param = @_;
  my $p1 = $param{Param1};
  local $\ = "\n";
  print "p1: $p1";
  print "p2: $param{Param2}";
}
```

Comment: If the intent is indeed to pass named parameters, this is also how I would do it. Requiring braces on the outside is a stupid waste of typing. I didn't get that impression however, especially given the other question the OP asked just before. (It wasn't me who downvoted.)

Comment: Ha.  I didn't suspect anything and I'm not worried about the downvotes.  I imagine someone didn't like the question and so downvoted all answers(?), their account could be closed in a week :)  I had instituted a practice, which you might scoff at.  For each subroutine I do…`my $args={@_}` for comprehension and consistency.  It might be less efficient, which I don't know how much of an impact that is, but it's helped.

Comment: I don't think having a few extra dereferences is going to affect your code's performance.

Comment: Well, if the great @ikegami says it's okay.. then I only need to add comments. `# ikegami said it was okay https://stackoverflow.com/a/51460050/183181` :P

Comment: oh wow, it looks like they've made some optimizations, because `$a->{x}` is the same number of ops as `$a{x}` since 5.22! The difference is now measured in CPU ops instead of Perl ops.